# iOS6 - Changing embedded subview in a view

Tags: uiview, ios6

I'm looking for some ideas what's the best way to implement the following behaviour (and a starting point in code/pseudo-code if possible):

- BookViewController with ViewA - contains some UILabels (e.g. information about a book)
- MainViewController with ViewB - contains some UI elements and displays ViewA in the middle (one view at a time)

The user should be able to swipe inside ViewB to view different books i.e. I will need to manage a number of ViewA views, create new ones and populate them with new data, and then replace the current instance visible in ViewB. So effectively I'll be changing views in the centre of the screen. What's the easiest and most efficient way to accomplish this functionality? Any suggestions comments are appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one view controller. It should control a scroll view with paging enabled at the center and e.g. three book views, one visible and the ones left and right of it. The controller should manage the data displayed in these book views.